# .net design pattern question

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to understand design pattern problems. I am trying to modify the code like this in winforms and trying to see if any design pattern suits my requirement. Please suggest which is the best design pattern in this scenario. This is very basic code containing 2 tab pages which might have different controls can be added dynamically and read out different files on click of particular tab. To elaborate more... I have written this code to learn and understand design pattern. This is just a scenario where user click on a particular tab which will show dynamic controls generated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name.Equals("tabPage1"))
        {
            GeneratedynamicControlsForTab1();
        }
        else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name.Equals("tabPage2"))
        {
            GeneratedynamicControlsForTab2();
        }
    }

    private void GeneratedynamicControlsForTab1()
    {
        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.Text = "Label1";
        tabPage1.Controls.Add(label1);

                }

    private void GeneratedynamicControlsForTab2()
    {
        tabPage1.Controls.Clear();
        Label label2 = new Label();
        label2.Text = "Label2";
        tabPage2.Controls.Add(label2);

                }



}
```

Please let me know if this below implementation is correct for above scenario
Please let me know if this implementation is correct to modify above code to state pattern.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    void GenerateControl(iState state)
    {
        switch (state.value)
        { 
            case 1:
                GenerateControlforTab1();
                break;

            case 2:
                GenerateControlforTab2();
                break;

        }
    }
    void GenerateControlforTab1()
    {

    }

    void GenerateControlforTab2()
    {

    }


private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     IState state = new State()

        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name.Equals("tabPage1"))
        {
            state.value =1      ;      }
        else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name.Equals("tabPage2"))
        {
            state.value =2;
        }
        this.GenerateControls();
    }
}

interface iState    {
    void GenerateControls();
}
```

Comment: what is your "requirement" and why are you doing this: dynamically creating the controls. have you noticed you always clear tabPage1

Comment: Hi, I have corrected the code. Requirement is on click of particular tab, dynmic controls should be addesd based on certain conditions fetched from database. Currently, I am only concentrating on design so have not making any calls from database.

Answer (score 0):

MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to implement the state pattern but there are some mistakes.One of the uses of State pattern is to remove conditional if statements from your code by creating state interface and implementing different states from it.But You've used switch statement instead of ifs.And in tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged function you use ifs again. You've created the interface iState and directly instantiate it.But I think you should have to create some concrete implementation on the iState interface where the state codes should go to.You can take a look on "O'REILLY Head first design Patterns" chapter-10 for guidance.